# Properly using derived state for animations React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component in my React Native code, let's call it `SliderComponent`. This component is shown or hidden using redux, and as such it has a prop `isVisible` passed to it via redux. The things about this component is that it is always shown or hidden with a sliding animation. My code looks something like following (unnecessary snippets of code are skipped):

```
class SliderComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // I am creating `isVisible` state because I want the animations
            // to control the actual showing/hiding of the component
            isVisible: false
        }
    }

    showBySliding() {
        this.setState({
            isVisible: true
        });

        // Start the animation
    }

    hideBySliding() {
        // First slide the component and hide it
        // then do this.setState({ isVisible: false });
        // in the animation callback
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.isVisible !== nextProps.isVisible) {
            if (nextProps.isVisible) {
                this.showBySliding();
            } else {
                this.hideBySliding();
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.props.isVisible) {
            return null;
        }

        // Have the component rendering logic
        // Example, in this modal, the actual decision of whether to show
        // or hide is actually determined by this.state!
        return <Modal
                visible={this.state.isVisible}
            />;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    // read state and decide if component is shown or hidden
    return {
        // This can be false as well
        isVisible: true
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SliderComponent);
```

The actual decision of whether to show or hide the component is taken by `this.state` but there is `prop` passed as well. Once I get the `isVisible` prop as true, I start out my component as hidden, then change the state to `isVisible: true`, and slide it up. When I have to hide it, I first slide it down, then set the `this.state.isVisible` to `false`.

My question is, How can I consolidate these `state` and `props` so that I **have a single source of truth for `isVisible`** and also have the ability to animate them properly?

Other readings I did: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: You're using `componentWillReceiveProps` but asking for derived state... a little bit unclear what you're asking for...

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I am using `componentWillReceiveProps` to detect a change in `this.props.isVisible`, and then set `state` which is actually showing or hiding the component. This is considered an anti-pattern, as mentioned in this post: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-erasing-state-when-props-change

Comment: so what's your question? asking how to replace will receive props with derived state?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I am asking that how can I depend wholly on either state or props to determine whether my component should be visible or not.

Comment: There's nothing wrong. We can depend on props otherwise how can we rely on receiving props?